# jQuery Mobile listview not refreshing properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I am getting the following error when I changePage to a listview, even though I have completely commented out my listview.('refresh') method. Safari loads my listview fine, but whenever I use chrome I run into problems. Has this happened to anybody else? I'm doing all of my loading in document.ready(){}

The issue even happens when I completely comment out my listview....

**Code that initiates changePage**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>First jQuery Mobile Example</title>

  <!-- the three things that jQuery Mobile needs to work-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./signup.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page starts here -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="surveyList">

<script>

$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme  = "c";
});

function createNewSurvey() {

    console.log("Creating new survey");

   $.mobile.changePage( "surveyCreator.html", { transition: "slide"} );
}

function goToSurveyResults(surveyID) {
  console.log("hello");
    console.log("This survey's id  is: ",surveyID);

    surveyId = surveyID;
    console.log("surveyId is = ", surveyId);

   // $.getJSON("http://iwaiter-app.com/iWaiter_scripts/getSurveyAnalytics.php?surveyID=" + surveyId, function(json) {
   //       console.log(json);

       console.log("surveyId is = ", surveyId);
         $.mobile.changePage( "surveyResults.html", { transition: "slide"} );
             console.log("changed page");
  //  });

}

function deleteSurvey(surveyID) {
  console.log("Deleting survey with id: ",surveyID);
}


//$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#surveyList').bind('pageinit', function() {

  var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var fullDate = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;

$('#footer').append('<p>  Today: ' + fullDate + '</p>');
//document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)

// get the JSON data from server
    $.getJSON("http://iwaiter-app.com/iWaiter_scripts/get_surveyList.php?email=alo@mit.edu", function(data) {

      console.log(data);

      // Define some local instance variables
      var listOfSurveys = data.Results;
      var currentDate;
      var numbersOrLetters;
      var onOff;
      var surveyDescription;
      var dataTheme;

       $('ul#surveyList').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(createNewSurvey());">Create New Survey</a></li>');

        for (i = 0; i < listOfSurveys.length; i++){

            // set whether the survey uses numbers or letters
            if (listOfSurveys[i].Numbers_or_letters > 0) 
                 {numbersOrLetters = 'Letters';}
            else {numbersOrLetters = 'Numbers';}

            // set whether survey is on or off
            if (listOfSurveys[i].On_off > 0) {onOff = 'Off'; dataTheme = 'data-theme="c"';}
            else {onOff = 'On'; dataTheme = 'data-theme="b"';}

            // Set description
            if (listOfSurveys[i].Survey_description != '')
              surveyDescription = ', ' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_description;
            else
              surveyDescription = listOfSurveys[i].Survey_description;

            // set surveyAuthKey
            var authKey = listOfSurveys[i].Survey_authKey;
            console.log("authkey: ",authKey);

          if (listOfSurveys[i].Date == currentDate) {
              // create row in same section

          /* old list element
                $('ul#surveyList').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(goToSurveyResults(' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_id + '));"><h1>' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_authKey + '</h1><p>' + listOfSurveys[i].Number_of_options + ' Options, ' + numbersOrLetters + ', ' + onOff + ', ' + surveyDescription + '</p></a></li>');
           */     
                 $('ul#surveyList').append('<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right"' + dataTheme + '><a href="javascript:void(goToSurveyResults(' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_id + '));"><h1>' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_authKey + '</h1><p>' + listOfSurveys[i].Number_of_options + ' Options, ' + numbersOrLetters + ', ' + onOff + surveyDescription + '</p></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteSurvey(' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_id + ')" data-icon="delete" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn "' + dataTheme + ' ></a></li>');


          }
          else {
              // otherwise create a new section
              currentDate = listOfSurveys[i].Date;
              console.log(currentDate);

               $('ul#surveyList').append('<li data-role="list-divider">' + currentDate + '</li>');

                $('ul#surveyList').append('<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right"' + dataTheme + '><a href="javascript:void(goToSurveyResults(' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_id + '));"><h1>' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_authKey + '</h1><p>' + listOfSurveys[i].Number_of_options + ' Options, ' + numbersOrLetters + ', ' + onOff +surveyDescription + '</p></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteSurvey(' + listOfSurveys[i].Survey_id + ')" data-icon="delete" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn "' + dataTheme + '></a></li>');
            }
          }
       console.log("Refreshed");
        $('ul#surveyList').listview('refresh');

    });

});

</script>


    <header data-role="header">
    <a href="Master_Survey.html" data-direction="reverse" rel="external" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
    <h1>My Surveys</h1>

  </header>

  <div data-role="myContent">

    <div id="surveysContainer">

      <ul id="surveyList" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete">
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>  




<footer data-role="footer" id="footer"></footer>

</div>

  </body>

</head>
</html>
```

**Page w/ Error**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>First jQuery Mobile Example</title>

  <!-- the three things that jQuery Mobile needs to work-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./signup.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page starts here -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="resultsListPage" data-add-back-btn="true">

<script>

$('#resultsListPage').bind('pageinit', function() {

  console.log("new page");
  /*
   $('ul#resultsList').append('<li>Mean: </li>');
       $('ul#resultsList').append('<li>Standard Deviation: </li>');

     $('#resultsList').listview();
        $('#resultsList').listview('refresh');
        */
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("how far?");
//document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)

// get the JSON data from server
    //$.getJSON("http://iwaiter-app.com/iWaiter_scripts/get_analytics.php?surveyAuthKey=alo-1", function(data) {

    //  console.log(data);

      // Define some local instance variables
     // var listOfSurveys = data.Results;
      var currentDate;
      var numbersOrLetters;
      var onOff;
      var surveyDescription;

      // header
      // $('ul#surveyList').append('<li data-role="list-divider">' + currentDate + '</li>');

/*
      // result rows
       $('ul#resultsList').append('<li>Mean: </li>');
       $('ul#resultsList').append('<li>Standard Deviation: </li>');
     */

     // $('#resultListContainer').html('<ul id="resultsList" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true"><li>Mean: </li><li>Standard Deviation: </li></ul>');

     //  $("#resultsList").listview();
     //  $("#resultsList").listview('refresh');

    //  $("#resultsList").listview()

       // $('ul#resultsList').listview('refresh');

 // });

});

</script>


    <header data-role="header">
    <a href="Master_Survey.html" data-direction="reverse" rel="external" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
    <h1>Survey Analytics</h1>
  </header>








<footer data-role="footer" id="footer"></footer>

</div>

  </body>

</head>
</html>


Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html don't use document.ready()

Comment: yep I actually already figured this out from another stack post...thanks anyway though!

Comment: Please format your code properly, the indentation is not structured.

Comment: @PhillPafford can you please make an answer out of your comment, as I think it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

don't use document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

Because of your error:

```
Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

Indicates that a `.listview('refresh')` is being called somewhere in your code on an element that hasn't been initiated as a listview yet.

In your code the only `.listview('refresh')` is the in the following bind:

```
$('#surveyList').bind('pageinit', function() {
     ...
     $('ul#surveyList').listview('refresh');
     ...
}
```

This will not be unbound when you changePage. That means that when you changepage and the pageinit event occurs, javascript will still try to execute the code in this block. But the the element is not on the current page and thus (probably) not properly initialized.